# Restricting column width in tables

Tags: tables, two-column, classicthesis

I'm using the table format below in my thesis. The template I'm using is Classicthesis.

What happens below, however, is that the long text in the second column runs out of the page. What's the issue... ?

Thanks, 
Anders

```
\begin{table}
  \myfloatalign
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xll} 
  \toprule
  \tableheadline{Author} & \tableheadline{Definition}
  \\
  \midrule
   Amit and Zott & “A business model depicts the design of transaction content, structure, and governance so as to create value through the exploitation of business opportunities.” \\
   Hamel & “The four boxes in the diagram represent the major components of a business model: customer interface, core strategy, strategic resources, and value network. These basic components are linked by three 'bridging' components: customer benefits, configuration of activities, and company boundaries." \\
   Hawkins & "In other words, a business model describes how an enterprise gears up its resources, planning capabilities and processes to the revenue producing potential of a specific product or service. By focussing in on this relationship to revenue producing potential, a new context is provided for assessing the planning and operational aspects of an enterprise, and for assessing the relationship between on-line and off-line trading environments." \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption[caption]
\end{table}
```

Comment: you have specified that the first column (which only has a word or two) is `X` which allows line breaking, and the second two columns are `l` which are single line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you want to add an answer an get the deserved rep? :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B not really but done anyway:-)

Answer (score 5):

you have specified that the first column (which only has a word or two) is `X` which allows line breaking, and the second two columns are `l` which are single line. You don't appear to have any data in the third column at all so perhaps

```
{lX}
```

instead of

```
{Xll}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias  ;alalalala